# How read a json file with coordinate and plot them in a map?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, coordinates, openstreetmap

I've a `json` file like:

```
[
  {
    "coordinate": [45.464743, 9.189135799999999],
    "Indirizzo": "Bike Sharing P.za Duomo Milano"
  },
  {
    "coordinate": [45.4664299, 9.1976032],
    "Indirizzo": "Bike Sharing P.za S.Babila Milano"
  },
  {
    "coordinate": [45.454943, 9.162632600000002],
    "Indirizzo": "Bike Sharing P.za Cadorna Milano"
  }, ...]
```

I want to make a map with openstreet map and add a marker for every coordinates and adress.

I tried this:

```
<div id="map_id" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
<script>
var map_var = L.map('map_id').setView([45.4642700,  9.1895100], 16);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map_var);

L.marker([45.4642700,  9.1895100]).addTo(map_var)
    .bindPopup('Milan')
    .openPopup();

$.getJSON( "bike_coordinate.json", function(json1) {
   $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
    var place = json1[i];
       // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
    var customIcon = L.icon({
    iconSize:     [38, 40], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [10, 40], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    popupAnchor:  [5, -40] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    }); 
    var marker = L.marker(place.coordinate, {icon: customIcon});
    marker_array.push(tmp_marker);    
    tmp_marker.addTo(map_var).bindPopup(place.Indirizzo);
    }
   });
});
</script>
```

But it only show the first marker that is not read in bike_coordinate.json, I think I write wrong code, can anyone help me, please?

I'm using openstreet map, leaflet.
I'm new with javascript, thank you all.

Comment: May be you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: I don't understand how to adapt it to my problem, I post a test below @EmptyBrain

Comment: I post it below but it doesn't work @chŝdk I don't understand how write it correctly

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work @chŝdk I don't understand how write it correctly, I tried google maps, but it's not what I'm searching for, I want to use openstreet map that doesn't require API key

Comment: @AliceG I posted an answer, to point out your problem.

Comment: If the example @nikoshr added isn't working for you I'd suspect you have some issues with somethibg like not including jQuery or the .json file not being where you expect it. What console errors do you have?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I've got this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index):217

Comment: That's another problem, you haven't included jQuery in the page, put this in the header of your page : `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`.

Comment: Yes as per the comment above you need to include jQuery on you page. That's what give you the $ variable

Comment: The problem now is that it can't find the file, is it correct to put the file on the same folder of the app python?

Comment: @AliceG You need to put it under your `/resources/ ` directory.

Comment: @chŝdk I tried in the folder of the running app, I tried in the static folder and I tried in the templates folder but nothing change

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with yoour project structure?

Comment: @chŝdk I managed to get it find the file, every step a new problem ahah: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null
    at Object.project (leaflet.js:5)
    at Object.latLngToPoint (leaflet.js:5)
    at e.project (leaflet.js:5)
...

Comment: Try to use `console.log(data)` inside the loop and debug the loop iterations and check if `marker`object isn't `null`.

Comment: @chŝdk  It solves my problem, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here, is that you are using an extra loop, when you were trying to loop over the `json` items.

In fact the `$.each()` is sufficient here, you don't need to use a `for` loop inside of it, and the `data` param of the `$.each()` callback function will hold the data you need, to fill `place` object.

This is how should be your code:

```
$.getJSON( "bike_coordinate.json", function(json1) {
   $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
    var place = data;
       // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
    var customIcon = L.icon({
    iconSize:     [38, 40], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [10, 40], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    popupAnchor:  [5, -40] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    }); 
    var marker = L.marker(place.coordinate, {icon: customIcon});
    marker.addTo(map_var).bindPopup(place.Indirizzo);
   });
});
```

If you read and iterate the data correctly, then all you need is to adapt your code  and assign the markers.

**Edit:**

Make sure to include all the required JS libraairies such as jQuery in your page and to place the file in the right directory under `/resources`, of your application so it can be read correctly.

Comment: Thanks for help! I tried your code but it doesn't work in my script, I don't understand why in every case it doesn't add any marker. What can I control to make it works?

Comment: what does the error say? Post the errror stack trace please.

Comment: It doesn't give me any error, I've only have any marker on the map

Comment: Try to put `console.log(data);`inside the loop and see what it gives in the console, click `F12`to check it.

Comment: I found this: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):217

Comment: You haven't included jQuery, put this in the header of your page : `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`.

Comment: @AliceG For the file you need to put it in the `/resources/` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Your code reading the JSON file works just fine, it's how you work with the resulting data that's at fault:

- you iterate twice over your array, once with `$.each(json1`, and a second time with `for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {`. One of them must go.
- you add a `tmp_marker` on your map that does not exist : use `marker.addTo(map_var).bindPopup(place.Indirizzo);` instead
- you use a `marker_array`variable that is not defined, remove it,
- you declare a custom icon but you don't set a `iconUrl` : it's required and breaks Leaflet. For example:

  ```
  var customIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png',
      iconSize:     [38, 40],
      iconAnchor:   [10, 40],
      popupAnchor:  [5, -40]
  });
  ```

You could write your code as

```
$.getJSON( "bike_coordinate.json", function(json1) {

     for (var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
        var place = json1[i];

        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var customIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png',
            iconSize:     [38, 40], 
            iconAnchor:   [10, 40],
            popupAnchor:  [5, -40]
        }); 
        var marker = L.marker(place.coordinate, {icon: customIcon});
        marker.addTo(map_var).bindPopup(place.Indirizzo);
    }

});
```

And a demo https://plnkr.co/edit/PJi8HzqTJJTB5SnJJnak?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for help! I tried your code but it doesn't work in my script, I don't understand why in every case it doesn't add any marker. What can I control to make it works?

Comment: The demo shows a working map that reproduces what you have in your question. Not much I can add, besides the point I've just added about `marker_array`. Can you modify my demo to reproduce your problem?

Comment: It's possible that the problem is that it can't find my file? But I've got json file both in the templates folder and app folder

Comment: You can open your browser dev tools and check in the Network tab if your file is loaded or not.

Comment: I found this in corrispondence to $.getJSON( "bike_coordinate.json", function(json1) { :
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):217

Comment: Then you're not loading jQuery. Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` somewhere before your script

Answer (score 1):

For those coming to this late via a search:

The code to define the customIcon should be outside the loop & function as it's definition is constant:

```
// Creating a marker and putting it on the map
    var customIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png',
      iconSize: [38, 40],
      iconAnchor: [10, 40],
      popupAnchor: [5, -40]
    }); 

$.getJSON( "bike_coordinate.json", function(json1) {
   for (var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
    var place = json1[i];
    var marker = L.marker(place.coordinate, {icon: customIcon});
    marker.addTo(map_var).bindPopup(place.Indirizzo);
    } 
});
```